# .NET Settings File Available Types

Tags: .net, settings, type-systems, settings.settings

When modifying a .NET settings file, I'm given a choice of types for a setting. However, not all of the types accessible by my project appear, even in the 'Browse' window.

What determines if a type can be used for a setting file setting?

I have a type I created that I would like to be able to save, and I want to know what I need to change about it to use it in a settings file.

(VS 2008 - .Net 3.5)

Comment: Anything that can be XML-serialized is usable (i.e. anything that has a default constructor).  Even those it doesn't show up in the Browse, you can type the full type name into the text box to add a setting of that type.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is "hack" around with the .settings and .Designer.cs files a little, as documented [here](http://blog.coretech.dk/scripting/add-custom-data-type-structure-to-mysettings-in-vbnet-wpf/).

If you create a custom type in your project, such as:

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public struct MyType
    {
        public string StringValue;
    }
}
```

To get it to show up as an option in the Settings editor, you need to add the first setting value that uses that type to the files, as follows:

SettingsFile.settings:

```
<Setting Name="SettingNameGoesHere" Type="MyApp.MyType" Scope="User">
  <Value Profile="(Default)" />
</Setting>
```

SettingsFile.Designer.cs

```
[global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
public global::MyApp.MyType SettingNameGoesHere {
    get {
        return ((global::MyApp.MyType)(this["SettingNameGoesHere"]));
    }
    set {
        this["SettingNameGoesHere"] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Blech! Some "homemade" types appear in the regular designer - without doing this hacking. Just not the one I want. Why do those appear without hacking?

Comment: I *think* that it doesn't pick up types that are in the same assembly/project. i.e. Any types that are in *other* assemblies that you reference will be available

Comment: p.s. The 'Blech!' was not targeted at you, but is just my discomfort with mucking around in designer code.

Comment: @Mashmagar, I guessed that - the thought of hand-hacking the files doesn't do much for me either =)

Answer (score 0):

What types appear in the 'Browse' window - I believe the answer is serializable types. Below is an example that worked for me (VS 2012, .Net 4.0).

Class with public serializable members:

```
class Person {
    public string Name;
    public int Age;
}
```

What to write in setting value in designer:

```
<Person xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Age>42</Age>
</Person>
```

Comment: Depends on what you consider "serializable".  Your example you don't have a the `SerializableAttribute` on the `Person` class, yet it's still able to be used in settings.  e.g. despite `typeof(Person).IsSerializable` being `false` it can still be used in settings.